# Zero latency to 8.8.8.8

Tags: latency

Tp-link wifi routers have built in system tools like ping and Traceroute.
Please see the outputs of ping and Traceroute commands from my Tp-link router. How can this be ? This happens only with 8.8.8.8, not with 8.8.4.4 or any other IPs

[image: Traceroute]

[image: Ping]

Comment: It seems likely that a device close to you is accepting `8.8.8.8` traffic.  It is trivial intercept and handle DNS traffic.

Comment: Does this router offer DNS Proxying? Did you set it to 8.8.8.8?

Comment: "a device close to you" should be Optical Modem right ? Since its only a single hop away ? Or could it be the ISP ?

Comment: Could it be DNS cache poisoning/DNS spoofing ?